# floating ajax content not wrapping as wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a three-column layout where the first column starts off with a sidebar. The sidebar is float:left. The other two columns are filled with product divs that are also float:left. After the sidebar ends, the additional product divs wrap underneath it in the first column, so that there are three product divs across.

The sidebar is created dynamically, and so is of variable length, sometimes very long. Also, I have the page set up to add additional content with an ajax call triggered by scrolling to the bottom of the page. The problem is that if the sidebar is longer than the original two columns of product divs, when I append additional content to the page, it's starting beneath the sidebar, and not continuing to wrap to the right of the sidebar beneath the original product divs.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="rightWideContainer">
   <div id="leftNavCol">
      <!-- sidebar content -->
   </div>

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   ...

</div>
```

and my CSS

```
#leftNavCol {
   position: relative;
   width: 270px;
   float: left;
   margin: 7.5px;
}

.threeCol {
   width: 270px;
   margin: 7.5px;
   float: left;
}
```

After the ajax call, I append the response using this JS

```
$(response).find('.threeCol').appendTo('#rightWideContainer');
```

I've looked through questions already on stackoverflow and am not seeing one that pertains directly to this issue. I tried hiding the sidebar, adding the content, and then showing the sidebar again, but the new content was still beneath the sidebar when it reappeared. That's kind of hacky anyway, and I'd like to avoid a solution like that if possible, but right now I'm just looking for options. Is there a way to make the ajax content continue wrapping on the right until the sidebar ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try keeping the sidebar and the product content separate. At the moment you have them inside the same wrapper div (#rightWideContainer). Why not have the sidebar outside of this wrapper and the #rightWideContainer floated next to the sidebar?

```
<div id="leftNavCol">
          <!-- sidebar content -->
</div>


<div id="rightWideContainer">

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   <div class="threeCol">
      <!-- product content -->
   </div>

   ...

</div>
```

Then your css:

```
    #leftNavCol {
       position: relative;
       width: 270px;
       float: left;  
    }

    #rightWideContainer {
       position: relative;
       width: 855px;
       float: left;   
    }

    .threeCol {
       width: 270px;
       margin: 7.5px;
       float: left;
    }
```

Comment: That was how I originally had it, but the sidebar was moved into the main content area to save horizontal space. We'd like there to be three columns instead of four.

Comment: @Brian R, the above solution takes up the same amount of horizontal space. #rigthWideContainer is the same width as 3 x .threeCol, if you want three columns rather than four just remove a .threeCol column and widen the remaining columns. If that makes sense..

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. In the approach you give above, there are three columns in rightWideContainer, and then the sidebar is a fourth column outside of that. In the approach in my first posting, the sidebar is incorporated into the first column of rightWideContainer, so there are only three columns.

Comment: No, in your first example there are 4 columns, the sidebar and then three .threeCol divs making 4 columns. What width is your #rightWideContainer that will make a difference to how many columns you are seeing with floated elements?

Comment: No, actually in my first example there are three columns:

Comment: "I have a three-column layout where the first column starts off with a sidebar. The sidebar is float:left. The other two columns are filled with product divs that are also float:left."

Comment: I've mocked up your example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o414q4eo/1/ 
All of your elements are float left, but your html markup has 4 elements in your #rightWideContainer.
If you are referring to visual columns, then that number will differ depending on the width of #rightWideContainer. In the fiddle example drag the results box bigger and smaller to see how columns are affected.
I've added the visual queue of red for sidebar and blue for products

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. In my first example I included three threeCol elements after the sidebar, but this wasn't meant to imply that there were four columns. I just included three threeCol elements to give the idea that these kept on repeating for a while. To answer your question, the original rightWideContainer had a width of 855px, so a width of three columns. As you noted, where the threeCol elements start to wrap will depend on how wide rightWideContainer is. In this case, the third threeCol element I show will begin a second row.

Comment: The question of three vs. four columns is really academic anyway. The main point is that I would like the sidebar to be in the main content area with the product divs wrapping around it.

Comment: Yes that's correct and that's the way that floats work, hence why your product is wrapping below the sidebar when they become larger than it, i.e. the next available left hand space is below the sidebar.
To get around this take the sidebar out of the product container (#rightWideContainer) and then make the width 570px and float it left against the sidebar. As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/o414q4eo/2/

Comment: Alternatively if you really want them in the same container as per your markup then you can use negative margins and padding, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/o414q4eo/3/

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions you've offered so far, but I'm not sure you're understanding what I'm trying to get. I actually *want* the product divs to wrap under the sidebar, once they reach the end of it (thus the reason I used float). The problem is that when I add additional product divs with ajax, they start beneath the sidebar whether the original product divs had reached that point or not. This might be unavoidable, but I'm trying to see if there is a way to have the new ajax content continue to fill the right two columns if the end of the sidebar hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: Ok, do you have an example of this in action? A URL I could look at?
Floated elements should wrap underneath the sidebar example here: http://jsfiddle.net/o414q4eo/4/ so it must be something to do with the way you are adding the ajax content.

Comment: Well that will teach me to not try a simple model first. I tried this in jsfiddle, and to my surprise it worked. It turns out I had a stray clearing element in my original HTML after the first set of product divs. I'm sorry about all the back and forth, and thanks again for taking the time. I'm not sure of the etiquette in this case. You basically led me to finding out the answer for myself, so does that mean I should give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I wont complain if you do ;)